# Cannot find preloaded image (emscripten)

Tags: javascript, c++, html, sdl, emscripten

I try to compile an SDL project to HTML5/JS using emscripten.

The files are in the `data` directory. I preload the directory with this code:

```
--preload-file data@
```

But if I run the compiled code, I get this error:

```
Cannot find preloaded image /res/img.PNG
```

The res directory is located inside the data directory. The directory and the files are loaded. I've checked it with `dirent`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SDL_image requires `--use-preload-plugins` or `-s STB_IMAGE=1`, etc.

[Compiling and Running Projects » Building Projects » Emscripten Ports](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#emscripten-ports)